# Is there any possible way to temporarily hide the blue dot then make it re-disppear again in GMSMapView?

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I found out that when isMyLocationEnabled is turned off then back on again, blue dot does not appear on the map anymore.

MyLocation variable gives `nil` result when this sequence of action is done.

Is there any possible way to temporarily hide the blue dot then make it re-disppear again?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `startUpdatingLocation()` before you set `isMyLocationEnabled = true`

Comment: Not just that, you actually have to restart the iOS GPS tracking cycle all over again. That is, first, to call stopUpdatingLocation(), then startUpdatingLocation(). I am wondering if there is other way besides doing something this complicated.